# What does it mean channel.id()?

Tags: webserver, netty, channel

I'm trying to count any "new" client who connect to my HTTP server based on Netty 4 CR1.
Before CR1, it seems that channel.id was unique for any requests from a client.
Now, I have a different channel id per request.

I would like to understand what unique meant ?
In my use case, how can I detect if the request come from the same client.

The API say : Channel.id()
"Returns the unique integer ID of this channel."

Link: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#id()

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means what the javadocs says... It is unique per Channel which means per connection. So if multiple requests are served via the same Channel the id will stay the same as the connection is not dropped.

Comment: I'm looking at the example : HttpStaticFileServer. It seems that the connection drop after every request because the channel id changes. 

` May 23, 2013 9:17:19 AM [HttpStaticFileServerHandler]  messageReceived
INFO: Channel id : -530815764
INFO: Channel id : -1375019911
INFO: Channel id : -195845856`

I think that the behavior was different in the past. 
If this is not a bug, how do you keep track of the current user connected ? I would like to develop something like a "session".

Thanks

Comment: Recently this channel.id() has been deprecated. This is no longger support by Netty 4.0 final.